# How append a row to a table using an angular row directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to append a row to a table using an angular row directive:

Here is the plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/RFT5e5kbdCJdpPLWUqFD?p=preview

When I click the "Add Isrc" button a new row should be added but its not working.

```
var isrcorderapp = angular.module('plunker', []);

isrcorderapp.directive("isrcrow", function(){
  return {
    restrict:'A',
    controller: 'isrcorders',
    template: '<td><input id="artist" ng-model="artist"/></td>\
                <td><input id="title" ng-model="title"/></td>\
                <td><select id="isrctype" ng-model="isrctype" ng-change="setState(state)" ng-options="s.type for s in recordingTypes" class="ng-pristine ng-valid"></select></td>\
                <td><input id="duration"/></td>\
                <td><input id="year"/></td>\
                <td><input type="button" value="Add ISRC" onclick="AddIsrc()" class="btn btn-small btn-success" />\
                    <input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="RemoveIsrc()" class="btn btn-small btn-danger" />\
                </td>',
    replace: false
  }
});

isrcorderapp.controller("isrcorders", function($scope,$http) {
    $scope.recordingTypes = [
        {type:'A'},
        {type:'B'},
        {type:'C'},
        {type:'D'},
        {type:'E'}
        ];

  $scope.AddIsrc = function() {
      var e;
      $('#isrctable tbody').append('<tr isrcrow> </tr>');
      return e = '';
    };



});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onclick="AddIsrc()"` needs to be `ng-click="AddIsrc()"` to call the method on the $scope.

jQuery is also missing on the Plunker and has to be added.

The row needs to be compiled in order for the directive to execute...

```
isrcorderapp.controller("isrcorders", function($scope, $http, $compile) {

    // ...

    $scope.AddIsrc = function() {
        var e;
        var tr = $('<tr isrcrow> </tr>');
        $('#isrctable tbody').append(tr);
        $compile(tr)($scope);
        return e = ''; // not sure what this is
    };
});
```

Updated plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/oxXZlsFIDAbBCYMDOYMH?p=preview

Comment: The return e = '' was to resolve an angular error manipulating the DOM. I am using coffee script and it was returning $('#isrctable tbody').append(tr) and the latest version of angular doesnt allow you to do that